# Is there a drop-in replacement for 4275 + 4276 hinge?

Tags: piece-information, compatibility, replacement-parts

Both parts are not in production since 2008.

Hinges in my sets are in various conditions, some of them are way too loose to my liking. No ones fault, I was active kid who built a lot. But now it's like 10 years too late to replace them with new ones. Or is it? I'd prefer original Lego brand replacement that can be used without changing anything else in building instructions, but other ways to replace them are welcome, too. Restoring the ones I have is another question (that probably was already asked).

[image: 4275] [image: 4276]

Comment: If their replacements are not to your liking, you can buy these pieces after market on BrickLink. They are not terribly popular, and were produced for a while, so prices are fairly reasonable.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I'm thinking of building my own Blacktron cockpits, so I'm open for replacements, but if I can't find them, I'll buy the ones from BrickLink. I *hope* i still have all my old ones for old sets, but I'm not sure anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly drop in replacements, this particular modified plate has no protrusions around the hinge, it's entirely flat.

I see two possible replacements:

44301 and 44302. However they "click" in angles of 22.5 degrees and have protrusions...

60478 in combination with 63868 (clip and bar connection) is freely rotating but ofcourse again protrusions...

Comment: "It's good when it's good enough" I guess. 44301 and 44302 would work most of the time.